# Удаление дубликатов по двум полям

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица звонков. При добавлении данных нужно сравнить что бы не было дубликатов. Сравнение только по допустим времени началу звонка с помощью поля Уникальное и `INSERT IGNORE` невозможно т.к. есть вероятность в один момент времени звонка с разных номеров т.е. один звонок в базу уже не попадет что нехорошо. Попробывал методом тыка добавить еще один уникальный на номер с которого звонят следуя логике что в один момент времени с одного номера неможет быть 2 звонка. Но в итого вообще занеслось на 30% меньше записей т.е. походу такой подход тоже неработает. Может кто подскажет как занести в базу значения по 2 полям.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы составной уникальный индекс из двух полей одновременно пробовали делать ? Приведите в вопросе какие уникальные индексы вы пробовали создавать в виде команд `create index`. Хотя что то мне подсказывает, что это надо тригером делать и в нем время как то округлять. иначе с разницей в 1 секунду уникальность не поможет

Comment: нужна уникальность - добавьте уникальный индекс по двум полям. А так описание проблемы не понятно, что там у вас вообще происходит, я лично не понял

Comment: Прежде чем удалять дубликаты, определитесь с тем, что именно надо считать дубликатом в вашей предметной области. Я слабо разбираюсь в телефонии, и потому могу представить несколько параллельных разговоров с одним и тем же номером как входящим так и исходящим вполне могу - многоканальные номера же есть.

Comment: Вот такая таблица с 2-мя уникальными ключами (id сам делаю его в отдаче нет). И пробывал команду `INSERT IGNOR INTO`

Comment: уникальные 2 поля если их использовать оджновременно именно start and to_number. `ALTER TABLE mango
 ADD UNIQUE INDEX to_number (`to_number`);` Подскажите как сделать составной уникальный индекс из двух полей?

Comment: Если речь о биллинге (или иной серьёзной системе), то дубликатом следует считать только полный дубликат - т.е. равенство по ВСЕМ полям записи. Если же принимается решение определять уникальность только по части полей - следует сначала чётко и однозначно сформулировать критерий, какую из двух записей-полудубликатов следует удалять, а какую оставлять. Чтобы гарантированно из пары удалялась одна и та же запись, вне зависимости от того, на чём, когда и кто это реализует программно. Пока такого критерия нет, думать "как" не имеет смысла.

Comment: Двойной это так: `ALTER TABLE `mango`
 ADD UNIQUE INDEX `start_to_number` (`start`, `to_number`);` Логика такая: после первого прогона когда данные занеслись первый раз, при следующих вставках сравнивается есть ли в базе строка с такимиже start and to_number если есть то вставка пропускается и инсерт идет дальше и так до конца вставки.

Comment: @ASYOU ну так вам нужен этот составной индекс и INSERT IGNORE. Ваше замечание про испытания методом тыка антинаучны и выводы сделаны неправильные.